# Simple audio player with <audio> tag not able to control time progress in chrome running on python server (but works on safari and node server)

Tags: python, html, node.js, django, google-chrome

Very basic audio player, running on python server locally. If I run it on safari, it works fine. If I run it on a node server, it works fine on chrome and safari. But ultimately this will be part of a django project and needs to run on python server.

For some reason on a python server (on chrome only),  the audio plays, but I can only stop or go back to beginning. If I click anywhere else on the audio it stays there. There are no errors in console. I do get this in the server log for my entire django project: [04/Jul/2023 12:04:39,230] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 61887). I am running python3.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audio Player</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Audio Player</h1>
    
    <audio controls>
        <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I had one shorter mp3 I left in browser for a while and came back 20 minutes later and it works now. But I refreshed the server and cleared cache and it again stopped working.